Using CCache with --coverage and unique paths
So long story short, we want to use CCache  to speed up our builds and for the most part it is working as expected.
In this particular build we use --coverage for GCOV/GCOVR
In this particular build our build path is different 99% of the time because our path contains the  particular commit SHA as a folder name in the path(the root of the repo).  I wont go into why this is the way but it is.
When i do a debug compile between two folders there are zero hits because there are differences.
Looking at the .ccache-input-text between two builds i can see the results are 99% the same but in each there is a #Absolute object file path that contains the entire full path, so  when CCache compares this is almost always different obviously because there's a different SHA named dir in the path.
Is there any way to make --coverage work  without duplicate paths? I'm honestly not sure its even possible as our build runner machines can build multiple PR's at the same time, so we use SHA folders to differentiate and target them.
